# Pandas DataFrame: query with variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a DataFrame query using 2 variables.
The first variable is the column label and the second is a list of values.
What I want to do is select all row where that column has a value contained in that list. The strange thing is that if I write the column label as a string there is no error, while referencing the variable containing the column label gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 2134, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4433)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 151, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4238)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 388, in pandas.index.Int64Engine._check_type (pandas\index.c:8171)
KeyError: False
```

This is the working code:

```
rhs_values_list = df1["RHS"].tolist()
query = "shoe_size in @rhs_values_list"
result_set = df2.query(query)
```

while this rises the above error:

```
rhs_values_list = df1["RHS"].tolist()
col = "shoe_size"
query = "@col in @rhs_values_list"
result_set = df2.query(query)
```

Is there something wrong with second version of the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is executing the actual query with `@col` in the string, not the value you bound to that variable.  You can use string interpolation e.g:

```
  rhs_values_list = df1["RHS"].tolist()
    col = "shoe_size"
    query = "{} in @rhs_values_list".format(col)
    result_set = df2.query(relaxed_query)
```

Comment: FYI using string interpolation like this is generally not a great idea.  Ideally you want to use a library that allows parameterized queries and will sanitize any variables.

Comment: In this case, SQL injection is not a concern because you cannot pass table mutation queries to `df.query`.

Comment: Good to know Pandas got your back :)